# how to call target method for a button implemented in base class

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my project i have  a Baseclass : UIViewController.I have created  a UIButton programmatically  and a target method for that button in base class.
 I have created a view controller which inherits from base class.The problem is the button is reflected on the screen but nothing happens when i click on it. Please guide how can i create an Action for the button inherited from base class

```
//method in base class that addss button
-(void)addRHSRoundButton{
    UIImage *imgNotSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MENU_NOT_SELECTED.png"];
    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:imgNotSelected forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     button.frame = CGRectMake(978, 340, imgNotSelected.size.width/2,   imgNotSelected.size.height/2);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(roundButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.tag= 101;
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}
```

Comment: Please post roundButtonClicked method.

Comment: -(void)roundButtonClicked{
    NSLog(@"btnClicked");
    button.hidden = YES;
    
}

Comment: Did you implement `-(void)roundButtonClicked` method in the subclass ?

Comment: yes its implemented in the base class

Comment: @AKST You should call [super roundButtonClicked] in subclass.

Comment: i don't understand what you want to do, can explain more better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method doesn't match you create target with method `roundButtonClicked` but you expect method RHSRoundButtonClicked to be run.

It's good if you pass button as a parameter. Amend your method like that:

```
-(void)RHSRoundButtonClicked:(id)sender
{ 
    NSLog(@"btnClicked"); button.hidden = YES; 
}
```

And change the line where you create button target to:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(RHSRoundButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

//Extended

If you want to call super class method you can call super instead of self:

```
[button addTarget:super action:@selector(RHSRoundButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

This should help.

Comment: i pasted wrong method by mistake i have corrected it please check the comments

Comment: tried passing button as a parameter still facing same problem